# Difference between sending a message and emitting it

Tags: semantics, messaging

Halfway through the [RabbitMQ tutorial](http://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html), I noticed that the tutorial stops referring to producers "sending" messages and starts using the verb "emit" instead — and pretty consistently, too; after the second tutorial, the verb "send" is no longer used to describe a producer transmitting messages.

Example:

[Second Tutorial](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html)

> The main idea behind Work Queues ... encapsulate a task as a message and **send** it to the queue. A worker process running in the background ....

[Fourth Tutorial](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-python.html)

> We'll use this model for our logging system. ... Let's focus on **emitting** logs first.

What is the difference between sending a message vs. emitting one?

Comment: sending has a destination emitting is detected by something else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in the context of the tutorial he is speaking in terms of broadcaster and listener objects. He is trying to explain that there is a logging object that broadcasts (or emits) messages and that is all it does.

Those messages don't go to a file.

The tutorial continues to explain that a listener has to attach to the logger to receive the messages. You can then attach a listener that does something with what it receives, for example: "writes it to a file."

In this context. The term `emit` is correct, because he's trying to explain an event system. Events have emitters and receivers.

Previously, I suspect he was using the term `send` correctly as well. You *send* things to a queue or *place* them in the queue. You do not *emit* or *broadcast* them into a queue.

A queue is a type of first-in last-out collection.

**EDIT:**

To clarify. lol

You do not `send` an event. You `send` data to the event listener. The event itself is `emitted`. I prefer the term `triggered` but that comes from naming event listeners `OnSomething`.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Ratchet Freak with his definitons:

> Sending has a destination emitting is detected by something else

However in this case I think it's just poor word choice by the author, as when writing logs, you do in fact have a destination.

Comment: Logs are sent in the sense that the data is sent to some physical location but Maybe they could be considered as emitted in the sense that they are put out for whoever may read them without knowing exactly who.